# java deprecation

Tags: java, annotations, deprecated

I am going to deprecate a class in java.

```
@Deprecated
class deprecatedClass
```

and I have list of this deprecated class, so going to add `@Deprecated` tag here too.

```
@Deprecated
List<deprecatedClass> listOfDeperecatedClass
```

and I have a method called

```
private populateListOfDeperecatedClass
```

This is a private method.  So do I need to add `@Deprecated` tag for this method too?

Comment: Please do not ask a question multiple times.

Comment: @Brian - read the questions again.  While there is a lot of text in common (sigh), this one is NOT a duplicate of the previous one.

Comment: @StephenC He probably should have just edited his original question instead of asking a new one. Also, he could have extrapolated his answer from one of the answers on that question.

Answer (score 1):

check the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.3.6) for a little more insight on deprecated

Answer (score 1):

There is no point marking private method @Deprecated. This is information for user of your class, if this method is private and not mentioned to be used just don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the class containing the method is not deprecated. All the private modifier means is that the method cannot be called from outside the class. If you do not mark it as deprecated, it can still be called from within the class without informing the user that it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

There is little point in marking a private method as deprecated.  It can ... by definition ... only be used by the current class.  Either replace / remove it immediately, or leave it as is.

Deprecation is primarily designed to flag problematic or outdated dependencies between different class.

Having said that, it is legal to deprecate a private method ... if you think it will help.